# Time restriction before accepting answer

Tags: discussion, answers

Is there a way for the site to enforce a minimal time limit before the question is allowed to be marked as 'accepted'? This should give more people a time to answer, and increase the quality of the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember correctly, new users have to wait ~15 minutes before they can accept. For own answers, OPs have to wait a day.

This is *usually* encouraged and or practised but users tend to go with what works for them at the moment and just accept answers. If something better or more indepth is posted, they can always unaccept the current one and accept the better one, **but in the end it is what the OP chooses** and when they decide to accept it.

We are a free and helping community, this is a learning experience for everyone and that is one reason why the ***edit*** functionality exists, most times questions can be improved or bettered with a few points etc. We can all chip in and make one good answer. If you feel however that your contribution merits a new answer, feel free to do so as multiple answers are always encouraged.

Comment: this sounds reasonable enough to me. Accepted! :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50703/192187